# git show - list the contents of a directory from the history

Tags: git

The command `git show` is extremely useful, including for listing directories, but its output in listing a directory causes some problems. For example, consider the following.

```
user@machine$ git show HEAD:src/
tree HEAD:src/

file0
dir0/
file1
etc/
...
```

The problem, here, is that it prints `tree HEAD:src/` and a blank line. I could easily split on the blank line, and take only the directory listing, but this seems needlessly complex. **I cannot use any other system tools, like `tr` or similar. I can only use git.**

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ls-tree` command instead:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD src/
```

`-r` instructs `ls-tree` to be recursive and `--name-only` simplifies output.

Comment: I was about to add that I needed the solution to work for both directories and files, but I realized that I need to separate the two anyway. Thank you!